# Illustrator CS6: Difference between layer and sublayer

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I was wondering if there was any difference between having objects in layers or in sublayers. Why I am asking -- I always thought it was just a matter of organization and I could manipulate with both in the same way, but now when I applied the same operation to all elements in layer and then sublayer, it behaved differently:

I wanted to apply **Transform each** operation (only scale] **on all objects of a layer**. I selected them by clicking the "target" button on the right of layer name. It **worked as expected** -- elements were scaled, but didn't change their position.

However, then I needed to create a very similar layer so I decided to have these two layers as sublayers of a new LAYER. But suddenly when I selected **all the objects of one sublayer** and applied the same **Transform each** operation, it **behaved as if it was grouped**, therefore it not only scaled, but also changed position.

So could you please help me understand the difference? Are there other differences I haven't come across yet? Or can I change this behaviour in any way?

Thanks for any explanations, tips or helpful resources. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are basically 3 general tiers of hierarchy in the Layers Panel.

```
- Layer
 - Sublayers and Groups (including clipping groups)
   - Objects
```

The only real difference is the way they are labeled and stacked in the Layers panel. Expanding a sublayer to see what's inside it is no different than expanding a `<group>` item to see what's inside that.

- You can have groups within groups, within groups.
- You can have sublayers within sublayers, within sublayers
- You can have groups within groups, within a sublayer
- You **can't** have sublayers within a *any* group

The only thing you **can't** do is have a sublayer within a group. i.e. No Group can ever have a sublayer within it.

For all intent and purposes, Illustrator sees sublayers pretty much the same as it sees groups. There's no definitive definition which purports to treat sublayers any differently than groups *other than nesting* within the Layers panel and *object selection*.

In terms of selection, with the Selection Tool or Group Selection Tool, Illustrator will select the *parent group* of the object selected if the object is within a group. However, with the same selection, Illustrator will *not* select the parent *sublayer* if the object is in a sublayer.

**So, basically, sublayers are the same as groups but with the nesting restrictions and overall internal object selection behavior of layers.**

Sublayers also offer the ability to set the **Layer Options**, such as non-printing, template, dimmed, etc., and to change their highlight color:

[image]

Some of those options aren't available for standard groups.

Comment: Add that newly created  objects will appear in the active layer while the only happens in groups if you isolate them. Also layers can have different preview colors and have dimming and tempolate options.Then its complete and ill upvote

Comment: Good point @joojaa added :)

Answer (score 1):

Option A) Make the first and second sublayers as different group. then just choose 1 group add adjustment. If you want to change the other group choose it in Layers panel (choose the group not the layer itself) then adjust.

Option B) Add New Layer put the your second Sublayer or group there then adjust differently

Layer Organising is good practice. You know where to find and adjust them accurately.

E.G. I have two Target logo here and it has different properties or Appearance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

WOW... I had this same problem!
Make a distinction between a sublayer and an object. I found a way!

Have a look at my solution.

[image: Layer Panel]

Here we have a "fake layer" between real layers.

What I do is:

1 - Select all layers

[image: 1 - Select all layers]

2 - In Options, choose "Options to Selection

[image: 2 - In Options, choose "Options to Selection]

3 - Change the Color

[image: 3 - Change the Color]

4 - Notice that all the layers had their colors changed but the object didn't!

[image: 4 - Notice that all the layers had their colors changed but the object didn't!]

This way you will be abble to identify what is LAYER and what is OBJECT.